# rails mandrill_mailrer gem use repeatable tag in template_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

I am having a template saved in mandrill having repeatable content. I am using mandrill_mailer gem from rails to send mail using this template. How do i specify the repeatable content in template_content

```
<tr mc:repeatable><td mc:edit="name"></td></tr>

(mandrill_mail template: "test template",\
  subject: "xxxxxxx",\
  to: "xxxxx@gmail.com",\
  important: true,\
  inline_css: true,\
  template_content: {'name' => "p1"}).deliver
```

I tried using template_content: {'name00' => "p1"} / template_content: {'name:0' => "p1"}
So many permutations and combination.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatables from the MailChimp template language aren't supported in Mandrill. For more details about using templates and some limitations, see the following resources:

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21694286-How-do-I-add-dynamic-content-using-editable-regions-in-my-template-

See the note there that says: "Mandrill supports one specific element of the MailChimp template language: editable content areas (also known as mc:edit regions)."

http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/mandrill-for-mailchimp-users#templates

Comment: Tnx for the clarification. Is there any plan to add this feature ?